# Двоеточие или тире при пояснении

Tags: пунктуация, тире, двоеточие

**Ты можешь реабилитировать деятельность компаний в соцсетях( : / —) создавать цепляющий контент, который будет разжигать интерес пользователей к бренду и будет запускать вирусное распространение.**

Здесь после главного предложения конструкция имеет пояснительный характер (не уточнение), однако двоеточие ставится после обобщающего слова перед однородными членами — не наш случай. Также двоеточие ставиться в БСП, где вторая часть содержит пояснение; однако здесь у нас голый инфинитив, грамматической основы нету — значит, это не БСП. Хотя  с натяжкой можно предположить, что это неполное предложение.

**Ты можешь реабилитировать деятельность компаний в соцсетях: (ты можешь) создавать цепляющий контент...**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смысл не очень ясен, предложение отредактировано в качестве варианта:

Ты можешь **реабилитировать** деятельность компаний в соцсетях: **создавать** цепляющий контент, который будет разжигать интерес пользователей к бренду и  запускать его "вирусное" распространение.

ПАС  http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123#pp123

При наличии слов, обязательно требующих раскрытия (пояснения) значения, ставится **тире**:  Пропуск союза может фиксироваться тире и в предложениях с достаточно определенными по значению словами, **но нуждающимися в пояснении с точки зрения пишущего**: Задача, поставленная перед отрядом, была трудная — до рассвета дойти до леса; Погода-то самая подходящая — пурга (П. Нил.).

Примечание. В подобных случаях при более **подчеркнутом** пояснении может употребляться и **двоеточие:**

**Все они [письма] о главном: перестройке в нашей жизни** (газ.); **Настроение одно: скорее добраться до дома** (газ.).

Answer (score 1):

*Пунктуацией* этого не исправить. Первое впечатление о смысле: деятельность *дискредитивовавших* себя компаний предлагается **реабилитировать**; некто, к кому обращаются на "ты", сможет (вероятно, при помощи некоего программного продукта) создавать контент (*цепляющий*: на мой вкус лучше *заставляющий на себя западать*), который вдруг разожжёт интерес к **бренду** (*какому, чьему* - реабилитируемых компаний?) и запустит **вирусное распространение** (воспринимается как "распространение вирусов"; видимо, английское слово viral переведено по буквам). Попытка угадать, что на самом деле:

> Вы сможете активизировать деятельность компании в соцсетях, создавая
>   привлекательный контент, который будет разжигать интерес пользователей
>   к вашему бренду и приведёт к его безудержному распространению.

Answer (score 0):

Прежде чем "шлифовать" пунктуацию, нужно закончить построение фразы, правильно передающей какой-то смысл. На мой взгляд, представленная фраза требует существенной переработки. Вот лишь некоторые проблемы.

Словосочетание "реабилитировать деятельность компаний" употреблено неверно, на мой взгляд. Реабилитация — восстановление доброго имени или прав — может относиться к компании, а не к ее деятельности. У английского слова rehabilitate есть смысл реорганизации деятельности компании, но можно ли его перевести на русский словом "реабилитировать"? И даже в английском rehabilitate относится к компании, а не к ее деятельности.

Трудно поверить, что создание цепляющего контента и есть восстановление в каком либо смысле, как это следует из структуры предложения. Возможно, следует говорить о том, что создание контента поможет восстановлению.

"Разжигание" интереса и "вирусное" распространение — переход на сленг, который кажется не вполне уместным в серьезной рекламе.

Даже если распространение чего-либо (а чего именно, в этом отрывке не сказано)
будет носить "вирусный" характер, остается вопрос о том, что значит "запускать распространение", сочетаются ли эти два слова, и есть ли смысл вообще говорить о каком-то "запуске" в данном контексте.